# Spring Boot isn't exposing proper repository routes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-repositories

(Note: [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/#initial) is the tutorial I am basing my work off)

I am attempting to develop a simple API in Spring Boot, however, the repository I create isn't exposed properly.

The model looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String genreName;
    private String genreDesc;

    public String getGenreName() {
        return genreName;
    }

    public void setGenreName(String genreName) {
        this.genreName = genreName;
    }

    public String getGenreDesc() {
        return genreDesc;
    }

    public void setGenreDesc(String genreDesc) {
        this.genreDesc = genreDesc;
    }
}
```

The repository looks like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.uts13244177.models.Genre;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "genres", path = "genres")
public interface GenreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Genre, Long>{
    List<Genre> findByGenreName(@Param("genreName") String genreName);
}
```

And the application class is unchanged from Spring Initializr:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookDatabaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookDatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Based on the above-linked tutorial I am using, when I run cURL on http://localhost:8080, I should see something along the lines of:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "genres" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/genres{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

However, I instead see:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

I am running OpenJDK 11, Spring Boot 2.5.0, with Maven 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether all the model classes and controller classes are in a **sub-package**.
means
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xnP.png

Comment: Thanks for that, turns out the problem was I had mistakenly put my model and repository one directory too high, so the main application class wasn't reading them.